# Envio de valores para BD deixa a aplicação muito lenta

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans

Eu criei um programa em java para captar o movimento de um sensor e depois enviar os dados para um Banco de dados, pra que depois o movimento seja acessado por outra máquina em tempo real (ou quase) de outro lugar. o movimento é captado perfeitamente, os dados são enviados, e a outra maquina consegue ler os dados na hora que os dados são atualizados no banco de dados. O problema é que quando eu começo a enviar os dados para o banco de dados, o programa fica extremamente lento, com um delay de mais de 6 segundos, não só no envio, mas em tudo.

O código que faz a leitura e o envio é o seguinte:

```
public static ScheduledExecutorService StartPrintFrames (final Device device)
{
    isPrinting = true;
    isPaused = false;
    final ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int[] x = new int[4];
                x = methods.GetFrame(device);
                tela.AtualizeBar(x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3]);
                tela.AtualizeHeartRate(x[3]);
                //ConnectionToDB.instance.SendFrames(x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3]);
                } 
            catch (BPException ex) 
            {
                Logger.getLogger(Classe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    printFrames = ses;
    return ses;
}
```

Da forma que está ele não manda os valores para o BD, pois a linha abaixo esta comentada, assim o programa roda sem delay nenhum, mas quando descomento essa linha o programa fica extramamente lento

```
//ConnectionToDB.instance.SendFrames(x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3]);
```

O método SendFrames() é o seguinte:

```
public void SendFrames(int v1, int v2, int v3, int v4)
{
    try
    {
        //frame 1,2,3,4
        String request = "UPDATE Tabela SET ent1 = ?, ent2 = ?, ent3 = ?, ent4 = ?;";
        PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(request);
        pst.setInt(1,v1);
        pst.setInt(2,v2);
        pst.setInt(3,v3);
        pst.setInt(4,v4);
        pst.execute();
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Alguém pode me dar uma luz de como resolver isso ou outra maneira de enviar os dados que não dê esse leg todo?

Comment: vc pode aumentar o tempo de intervalo entre os updates ou otimizar o seu pojo... a banda da hospedagem tmbm interfere.

Comment: Tem certeza que deseja atualizar a tabela? Isso parece-me muito mais como uma nova inserção

Comment: É isso mesmo, não quero salvar os valores, só manter um update no banco de dados

Comment: @RobertoJunior: No comando UPDATE do método SendFrames não consta a cláusula WHERE, o que faz com que todas as linhas da tabela sejam atualizadas. Há uma única linha na tabela?

Comment: sim, só há uma linha na tabela